# How do I construct local constants from values returned during runtime?

Tags: c#, constants, readonly

I want 'filename' to be constant:

```
string filename = "WR" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M_dd_yyyy") + ".xls";
```

I also want to keep filename as a local and not a field.(I know readonly can solve the problem that way)

Comment: **DateTime.Now** defeats the const...

Comment: Yes i know that. Shouldn't it behave like consts in c++?

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, you want to make a method local variable constant (i.e. untouchable) ? You can't...

Comment: Similar applies to why you cannot use DateTime in attributes.

Comment: So i just can't make it 'unmodifiable'? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `readonly` variable. It can be initialized during declaration and changed in the constructor, but nowhere else. And, it only applies to fields, not local variables.

```
private readonly string filename = "WR" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M_dd_yyyy") + ".xls";
```

As for why you can't use a `const` this way - From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time.

And, of course `DateTime.Now`, can't be.

Comment: I wanted a local actually. I know that readonly can be applied to only fields and not locals. Anyway. Thanks.